# Linear regression with ARIMA errors variables selection

Tags: statistical-significance, forecasting, arima

I have constructed linear regression model with ARIMA errors. Here is an output:

[image: Output]

Standard error of my IV coefficient seems to be very large compared to the coefficient itself. Can I conclude that this coefficient is not significant and there is no point in using this model for forecasting?

Comment: When it comes to forecasting, a good measure of whether a variable should be included in the model is whether it reduces the AIC. Thus you may compare the AIC of the model *with* the variable against the AIC of the model *without* the variable. Choose the model that has the lower AIC. **Also,** consider changing the title of the post to a more relevant one. Your goal seems to be variable selection for successful forecasting rather than interpretation of a function.

Comment: The t test, an inferential statistic, suggests that there is no statistically significant incremental value in incorporating/using a particular variable/coefficient thus parsimony would suggest not using it assuming that the model erorrs are Gaussian . The AIC statistic is simply a descriptive/summary statistic reflecting a modification of the error variance based upon the total number parameters estimated and the sample size

Comment: @IrishStat, I am trying to understand what you meant. Since the focus is on forecasting, AIC is the relevant statistic (assuming the loss function is defined as mean squared forecast error) when it comes to inclusion or omission of variables. Is that wrong or irrelevant? Do you suggest using the $t$ statistic instead?

Comment: @RichardHardy From Wikopedia "it deals with the trade-off between the goodness of fit of the model and the complexity of the model.

AIC does not provide a test of a model in the sense of testing a null hypothesis; i.e. AIC can tell nothing about the quality of the model in an absolute sense. If all the candidate models fit poorly, AIC will not give any warning of that."  The AIC is defined as  = 2k - 2\ln(L) where L is the error variance and k = degrees of freedom ..... see my answer as not enough room ...

Comment: AIC does not provide a test of a model in the sense of testing a null hypothesis; i.e. AIC can tell nothing about the quality of the model in an absolute sense. If all the candidate models fit poorly, AIC will not give any warning of that." The AIC is defined as = 2k - 2\ln(L) where L is the error variance and k = degrees of freedom. It is similar to an adjusted R-Square. Model selection / identification is not conducted in a kitchen-sink manner but rather in a careful augmentation/reduction i.e. sufficiency/necessity manner yielding a model that has enough statistically significant parameters

Comment: This post continues a tangential comment thread: it does not appear to answer the question. Why don't you start a chat room to continue this discussion with @RichardHardy?

Comment: He asked "Is that wrong or irrelevant " I answered (politely) an implicit  definite "Yes" .In terms of the OP's question , my comments / answer would answer the question by providing reasons that the t test should be used and that the AIC nor be used to identify the model (for whatever purpose)

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think that when it comes to forecasting, model parameter significance plays very limited role. Meanwhile, AIC will asymptotically select a model with the lowest mean squared forecast error, whatever the pool of models is being considered, as long as that pool is fixed. That was my point with regards to the OP where there is a pool of only two models: one including the regressor `df2$tootus.lag` and the other one excluding it.

Comment: (Continued) I did not claim that AIC tells anything about the *absolute* quality of the model -- but it does tell something about the *relative* quality given a pool of competing models. So I think we are not really disagreeing much but just taking different assumptions and focusing on different issues. Anyway, I appreciate the clarification given in the answer. At the same time I still maintain (perhaps wrongly) that my first comment on the OP is correct.

Comment: Your caveat "as long as the pool is fixed" suggests the flaw in your approach. Modern model identification does not/ may not start with the "final answer in the set of possible models" but rather evolves iteratively often from a reasonable prior but not necessarily so. You approach is similar to one where one assumes models and picks the best and if unhappy often suggests getting new data which better fits the assumed prior list of model(s). Social scientists often tacitlely ignore the "information in the data" as it was not known a priori.

Comment: Very good that we clarified *why* and *where* we disagree! The devil was in the assumptions. Once we agree on the assumptions, I think the main reason for disagreement disappears. I do not contest your statements that are based on your assumption of non-fixed model pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked "Can I conclude that this coefficient is not significant and there is no point in using this model for forecasting? " . My answer is yes you can conclude that there is no point in using this for forecasting based upon the model fitting statistics. One might argue that if you withheld observations from a number of origins and compared the resulting forecasting out-of-sample values you might get another "opinion" of your two alternative models.

Comment: A note that might provide extra insight. *One might argue that if you withheld observations from a number of origins and compared the resulting forecasting out-of-sample values you might get another "opinion" of your two alternative models.* Asymptotically, this would be equivalent to comparing the AICs of the two models. Consult e.g. KONISHI, S. & KITAGAWA, G. 2008. *Information criteria and statistical modeling*, Springer Science & Business Media, especially pages 249-250.

Comment: If you re-estimate parameters at each origin you will not have the same results as the one-time AIC using all the data thus the conclusions could be quite different regarding the quality/forecasting accuracy of the two models.

Comment: I cannot see the problem here. The AIC of the *full* sample replaces (asymptotically) the time-series cross validation using *subsamples*.

Comment: You would have to prove that to me using actual data as re-estimation at each origin would generate different forecasts and different error measures unless the re-estimated parameters were identical for all origins.

Comment: I agree that for each iteration of time-series cross validation the estimated coefficients, their significance etc. will be different. However, this is not important as the conclusion regarding inclusion versus omission of the variable of interest will be based on *all of the iterations taken together*. Meanwhile, using AIC is an alternative to doing time-series cross validation. Taking the AIC of the model based on the whole sample and comparing it with the AIC of the competing model replaces the computationally intensive procedure of time-series cross validation using the two models.

Comment: I disagree as updated analysis yielding new forecasts is quite different than a one-time simple statistic. I repeat my request that you numerically prove your statement otherwise it is unsubstantiated in my opinon.

Comment: The explanation is in the Konishi & Kitagawa's (2008) textbook referenced above. Perhaps there is a proof in the textbook, too (I do not have the textbook on my shelf so I cannot check quickly).

Comment: The idea that 1 simple statistic is the equivalent of multi-origin analyses with parameter re-estimation is to me an oversell of a "keep-it-simple approach" because doing it right would be "burdensome" . Unfortunately doing it right requires effort.

Comment: What about Stone's famous paper where he shows that AIC is equivalent to leave-one-out cross validation in a non-time series setting? STONE, M. 1977. *An asymptotic equivalence of choice of model by cross-validation and Akaike's criterion.* Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series B (Methodological), 44-47.

Comment: but this is time series ....

Comment: As I said before, for the case of equivalence between AIC and time-series cross validation refer to Konishi & Kitagawa's (2008) textbook. I only referred to Stone (1997) to provide *another* example and to show that the time-series case is not unique with respect to the equivalence between AIC and cross validation.

Comment: ok I await your numerical example to support your contention. Please send it to me at dave@autobox.com